# JavaScript error invalid quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

This javascript code:

```
var regex = /(?<=<img src=").*?(?=")/gm;
var src = regex.match(str);
```

Gives me this error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid quantifier ?<=<img src=").*?(?=")
    in eval() line 0
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you use `eval` to create RegExp objects? You should not.

Comment: I don't think JavaScript supports lookbehinds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your question marks like so:

```
/(\?<=<img src=").*?(\?=")/gm
```

EDIT:

The above fixes your "invalid quantifier" problem. But, as @Pointy points out in his comment, `RegExp` objects contain no `match` function. You're likely looking for `match` on a string. (e.g., `"string".match(/reg(exp)/);`).

Comment: if i do that , i get a new error in the next line . TypeError: regex.match is not a function

Comment: @rajat that's because there is no method called "match" on regular expression instances. I think you're looking for "exec" or "test".

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [match()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) format

```
var src = str.match(/(?<=<img src=").*?(?=")/gm);
```